# How to upgrade JRE

Tags: java

Is there anyway to upgrade the installed JRE in the system? We are having 1.5.0_08 installed in out HP Unix system.We have to upgrade this to 1.5.0_15.Is there a way to patch up the existing JRE and upgrade to a newer version.Or can this only be achieved by installing the newer JRE and set this in the system PATH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's usually done is to have multiple JRE installed in separate directories (JRE_1_5_10, JRE_1_5_16, JRE_1_6_3, ...) and use some symlinks as references as JRE_1_5 that will point to the latest version of JRE 1.5, same for JRE_1_6, and eventually, JRE that will point to the latest version of the JRE.

Doing so, you just need to update the symlinks when you choose to use a newer version and always refer to the symlinks for systems that are "upgradable".

Comment: They call this method "alternatives" that controls symlinks in the /etc/alternatives directory, which is on the system PATH.   I usually bail out and dont use this method.  I prefer to install the Oracle JDK from the .bin file, which doesn't know about the "alternatives"system and then i update the symlinks myself using a shell script ran as "sudo".

Answer (score 0):

I'd always just upgrade and change the one in the path. But if it was only class library changes you needed, and not JVM you could replace the contents of the lib directory. But this is asking for disaster.